# How do I read in a list of bags in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

How do I read in a list of bags in Pig?

I tried:

```
grunt> cat sample.txt
{a,b},{},{c,d}
grunt> data = LOAD 'sample.txt' AS (a:bag{}, b:bag{}, c:bag{});
grunt> DUMP data
({},,)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default method for reading data into Pig is `PigStorage('\t')` -- that is, it assumes your data is tab-separated.  Yours is comma-separated.  So you should write `LOAD 'sample.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS...`.

However, your data is not in proper Pig bag format.  Remember that a bag is a collection of tuples.  If you cannot pre-process your input, you'll have to write a UDF to parse input of the form you have given.  So this *ought* to work:

```
grunt> cat tmp/data.txt
{(a),(b)},{},{(c),(d)}
grunt> data = LOAD 'tmp/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a:bag{}, b:bag{}, c:bag{});
grunt> DUMP data;
(,,{})
```

What went wrong?  The fact that your input field separator (`,`) is the same as the bag-record separator is confusing Pig.  It parses your input into the fields `{(a)`, `(b)}`, and `{}`, which is why only the third field ends up being a bag.  It's why you'll see a warning message like `Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 2 time(s)`.

If you can, try to use tabs or spaces (or semicolons, or...) instead of commas:

```
grunt> cat tmp/data.txt                                                                
{(a),(b)}       {}      {(c),(d)}
grunt> data = LOAD 'tmp/data.txt' AS (a:bag{}, b:bag{}, c:bag{});                      
grunt> DUMP data;
({(a),(b)},{},{(c),(d)})
```