# How to load bag data in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

Here is my sample bag data and my file name is bag.txt:

```
{(8,9),(0,1)},{(8,9),(1,1)}
{(2,3),(4,5)},{(2,3),(4,5)}
{(6,7),(3,7)},{(2,2),(3,7)}
```

Now i want to load this data in my Apache Pig shell when I am loading this data using

```
A = LOAD '/home/mvsubhash/Desktop/bag.txt' AS (B1:bag{T1:tuple(t1:int,t2:int)},B2:bag{T2:tuple(f1:int,f2:int)});
```

But my final result is like this

```
({(8,9),(0,1)},)
({(2,3),(4,5)},)
({(6,7),(3,7)},)
```

In the above result second bag is not processing.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160400/how-do-i-read-in-a-list-of-bags-in-pig

Answer (score 0):

By default the delimiter used for reading the file in Pig is tab(\t).Since your records is a comma seprated bags.Try using PigStorage(,)

```
A = LOAD '/home/mvsubhash/Desktop/bag.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (B1:bag{},B2:bag{});
```

Comment: If I m using above statement i m getting result as(,)(,)(,)

Comment: Edited the query..try this

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160400/how-do-i-read-in-a-list-of-bags-in-pig

Comment: I m getting same out put if i try this above query also (,)(,)(,)

Answer (score 0):

This data is not in format which Pig can process, as the record separator inside bag is similar to record separator between fields in a row i.e ',' so this can only be done using UDF.

But if we represent the field separator in record as Semicolon  ";"

Then we can load the data using:

```
grunt> Data = load 'bag_data' using PigStorage(';') as (Bag1:bag{tuple1:(A1:int,A2:int)},Bag2:bag{tuple2:(B1:int,B2:int)});
grunt> Dump Data;
```